# How to access app.controller $scopes inside app.directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Ok i have the following angular js code. What im trying to do is to set some scopes to null when enter button is pressed inside a form. So far I have div with ng-click event that sets these scopes to null, but i want to make the same with enter key also.

App directive:

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                //access scopes here like that
                //$scope.eurval = null;
              //$scope.usdval = null;
              //$scope.otherval = null;
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

App.controller

```
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
              $scope.eurval = null;
              $scope.usdval = null;
              $scope.otherval = null;
});
```

Comment: If your directive is inside the controller in your html file, the default scope is inherited from the controller.

Comment: @Arpan is correct, just make sure you're referencing the passed-in variable name (in your case `scope`, not `$scope`) in your directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a method that will do that for you:

```
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.eurval = null;
        $scope.usdval = null;
        $scope.otherval = null;
    };

    $scope.reset();
});
```

Then use it inside the directive:

```
if(event.which === 13) {
    scope.$apply(function (){
        scope.reset();
        scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html file, if your directive is inside the controller, it (by default) inherits the scope from the controller. Something like this -

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input my-directive type="text">
</div>
```

Then, you can access the controller's scope within the directive using the passed in variable, in your case `scope`, and not `$scope`.

[Here's an article](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/) detailing the different kinds of directive scope.